# Using org.apache.poi.ss.examples.html.ToHtml.create(...) in Android crashes

Tags: android, excel, crash, apache-poi, dalvik

When trying to convert excel file to Html using org.apache.poi.ss.examples.html.ToHtml.create(...), the call crashes with exception

```
02-28 13:16:06.559: I/dalvikvm(8010): Could not find method org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create, referenced from method org.apache.poi.ss.examples.html.ToHtml.create

    String xlsxFile = "/sdcard/book1.xlsx";
    String htmlFile = "/sdcard/download/out.html";

        try {

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(htmlFile);
            org.apache.poi.ss.examples.html.ToHtml.create(xlsxFile, new PrintWriter(fw));
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have all the required jars on your classpath. See the [POI Components Page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) for the list of the Jars you need. (If you downloaded a POI binary release, you'll have all of them in there, or if you use Maven it'll download them for you.)

Specifically, in your case, you're missing the poi-ooxml jar, and possibly its dependencies too - see the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) for the list of those.

Comment: When trying to run it I'm getting: "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Java heap space" and also "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space".
I have 4GB RAM on my computer and the properties in eclipse.ini are: -Xms128m 
-Xmx512m

Comment: Sounds like a different problem, you might get more help if you asked it as a new question

Comment: Can anybody here tell me how can I read and display .doc or .docx documents using Apache POI library? I made a demo project with above code and when I run it, I am getting "Conversion to dalvik failed with Error 2". Please share some code if you have

Comment: @YuDroid Sounds like you should ask a new question, rather than commenting on an old one

Comment: I am facing the same issue as faced by Alexei Robsky. So its better not to populate SO with unnecessary duplicate questions..

Comment: He asked about Excel files, your query is on Word ones, so it's not the same thing and needs to be a different question!